# decode in PHP a simple text from database

Tags: php, decode

I have a simple text into my database with a string like this:
"Online il nuovo sito web di QINT'X: rinnovato nella grafica presenta una struttura più lineare e facilmente fruibile rispetto al precedente, a tutto vantaggio della navigazione"

I have make a query in PHP to retrieve data but when I take the string doesn't decode the character'ù'. Why?
This is my code (I have hidden the part of query because the problem I think is in the utf8_decode):

```
echo'<span class="txt_page" style="text-align:justify">'.utf8_decode(htmlentities(substr($news['descrizione_it'],0,200))).'</span><br />';
```

Comment: It's the utf8_decode indeed , what language is in the text ? It's will be helpful in order to find the proper decoding needed

Comment: Is italian, I'm using this language in many and many sites and I haven't had this problem

Comment: Maybe the phpmyadmin (or whatever db admin you use) deconding settings are not correct

Comment: Learn how to handle encodings: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set encoding when you connect the DB.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8'
```

Comment: How? Can you write me a simple example please?